# Vertical screen and hot corners

Tags: unity, multiple-monitors, compiz, 15.10

Two of my hot corners are not working...
...In some cases.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 and have set the options in ccsm (doubled checked with the unity tweak tool). I've assigned all corners to a specific mission. Yet, two of them are not working, bottom right and top right.

I have two screens, one vertical to the left and one horizontal to the right. The screens are slightly shifted -> the bottom edge of the two screens is not aligned.

The thing is, from what I understood, for hot corners Unity considers the smallest rectangle including both desktops. That way, in my case, the bottom right and top right corners are out of my reach.

But resizing windows in the corners works just fine, for both screens.
I don't get it then, is it a bug or did I miss something? Can I get the two other corners to work?